Flexbox child item width doesn't fit the content width
I have an issue with the Flexbox child item. It doesn't fit with the content width. The code is below.



.pw-event-options {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 280px;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 280px;
  flex: 0 0 280px;
  max-width: 280px;
}

.pw-list-item-item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.align-items-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center !important;
  -webkit-align-items: center !important;
  -moz-box-align: center !important;
  -ms-flex-align: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}

.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  display: -webkit-flex !important;
  display: -moz-box !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
}

.pw-list-item-item.pw-event-options a {
  border: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 80px;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 80px;
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  max-width: 80px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.pw-list-item-item.pw-event-options .pw-moderation-type {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ececec;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20.5px;
  border-radius: 20.5px;
  color: #222;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 130px;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 130px;
  flex: 0 0 130px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 41px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.2307692308;
  max-width: 130px;
}
<div class="pw-list-item-item pw-event-options">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512"></svg>
    </a>
    <div class="pw-moderation-type">OFF</div>
  </div>
</div>



flex-grow: 1; will take the full space, but I don't want that. I want <div class="d-flex align-items-center"></div> will take the content width not the full width of the box.

The issue with your code maybe that the .pw-list-item-item container has the align-items: center property set by default. This makes the child elements stretch to fill the available space within the container, even if their content is smaller.
You can try this :
.pw-list-item-item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;  
  align-items: flex-start;  /* Change here */
}


@Sonia align-item: flex-start; not working. I have tried.
